# Oauth2 for personal use

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api

I want to use Oauth2 personally because I am trying to use the google APIs. I do not have intention of making an app for others. But the Credentials for Oauth2 require a authorized domain with certain pages already created.
So how can I use OAuth2 without the domains? Or is there another way to accept google apis without this process?

I looked into Oauth playground but the tokens get revoked within 24 hours. I need something where I do not constantly need to get new tokens or where I can automatically generate tokens.

Comment: OAuth Tokens expire. You will need to handle this. I have not verified this, but I don't think you need (as in required and validated) a domain. You can use localhost for testing. However, as a developer, spend the $12.00 and purchase your own domain. Google has the new `dev` domain. You could be `www.uncommon.dev`.

Comment: The problem is I am using google sheets API which is a sensitive scope so it requires verification. But I only care about looking at my own data.